# Disable query result and document cache in solr and only use filter cache in solr?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I tried setting the size of the document and query result cache to zero but still it is not getting disabled. I see a lot of evictions in these caches as its size is zero.
How do I completely disable the use of all other caches except the filter cache in solr.

Here is my solr config snippet.

```
   -->
     <!-- disabled -->
    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                      size="0"
                      initialSize="0"
                      autowarmCount="0"/>

    <!-- Document Cache

         Caches Lucene Document objects (the stored fields for each
         document).  Since Lucene internal document ids are transient,
         this cache will not be autowarmed.
      -->
      <!-- disabled -->
    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="0"
                   initialSize="0"
               autowarmCount="0"/>
```

**Edit 1**

Commenting, or setting enable=false or setting the size zero doesnt work in solrconfig

If we pass cache=false in q param then I am able to turn off queryResult cache but still could not find a way to turn off document cache

Comment: You should be able to set `enabled="false"` for the cache to disable it. Another option may be to remove the definition completely, but I'm not sure if it'll create a default cache in that case.

Comment: sure will try that, didn't find "enabled" option in the docs. I will run 2 seperate tests, one with enabled false and one by commenting it out.

Comment: doesnt work with commenting or zero size

Comment: The parameter is `enabled`, not `enable`. Also make sure that you're actually reloading the configuration - i.e. if you're running Solr in cloud mode, that you're uploading the configuration to Zookeeper. Do you see a change in size reflected in the status page? You can see the usage of the `enabled` parameter in the examples here: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/7d0cf0df3286dba2354fc854a64eac5dcc09961a/solr/core/src/test-files/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig-managed-schema.xml

Comment: yes uploading it to zookeeper seeing the change as well. I used enable because in solrConfig the lru cache is controlled by enable param , See this     <cache enable="${solr.ltr.enabled:false}" name="QUERY_DOC_FV"
           class="solr.search.LRUCache"
           size="4096"
           initialSize="2048"
           autowarmCount="4096"
           regenerator="solr.search.NoOpRegenerator" />...   I will try again with enabled

Comment: forgot to mention, it worked, posting it in the answer so if anyone reads this . And Thanks @MatsLindh for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable a cache put enabled =false

```
 <!-- disabled -->
<queryResultCache 
                enabled ="false"
                class="solr.LRUCache"
                  size="0"
                  initialSize="0"
                  autowarmCount="0"/>
```

By doing this it will remove it from the plugin/stats screen as well